# Как сложить 2 двоичных кода?

Tags: c++

Как сложить 2 двоичных кода и чтобы в ответе опять получить двоично кодовый формат? Например: 0001 + 0010 = 0011

```
    {
    int d = 0000;
    int e = 0001;
    int g = 0100;

    int h = d + e + g;
    cout << h; // должен быть 0101, а выдает 65. На Visual Studio 2012 C++ Console Application
}
```

Comment: Это называется не "Сложить два числа", а "Как напечатать число в двоичном представлении". Правильный вопрос - половина правильного ответа. Минусую за бардак в голове.

Comment: лучше бы ответом помог. Минусовать всякий умеет -_- @mikillskegg

Comment: Во-первый, неправильно инициируются переменные. В С++ если числовой литерал начинается с ноля, это означает восьмеричную кодировку. В С++ нет литерала для двоичных значений чисел. Как это ни прискорбно.

Comment: @navi1893, переведите Ваш двоичный код в шестнадцатиричный (в голове (или на бумажке) это не сложно) и пишите в программе его.

--

Для вывода числа в желаемой системе счисления выводите остатки от деления числа на основание системы счисления. Повторяйте, пока число больше нуля. В конце реверсируйте результат.

Comment: > int g = 0100;
эээ. Вообще-то это восьмеричное число

Comment: @navi1893 я тоже поставил минус, но не потому, что умею, а за бардак в башке в квадрате...

Comment: @Barmaley мне как то все равно. На здоровье. Я не гоняюсь тут за цифрами

Answer (score 5):

Операция сложения по своей природе одинакова для двоичных и десятичных чисел.

Другое дело, что может возникнуть задача преобразования строки вида "0001" в десятичное число, чтобы в дальнейшем выполнить над ним арифметические операции. Для этого подойдет класс [std::bitset<>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/bitset/). Небольшой пример:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::string str_value("0010");
  std::bitset<10> dec_value(str_value);

  std::cout << " Binary value: " << str_value <<", decimal value: " << dec_value.to_ulong() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Аналогичным образом можно перевести десятичное число в двоичное представление, используя метод `bitset::to_string()`.

Comment: нет, мне нужно так и оставить в двоичном виде. Но он автоматически преобразовывает его =/ пишу 0001 + 0010, ответ выдает 65. Но мне нужно получить 0011. Как сделать? @vladimir_ki

Comment: Уточните вопрос: где вы пишете? В исходном коде? фрагмент кода приведите хотя бы.

Comment: @vladimir_ki обновил код

Comment: @navi1893, вот видите, вам нужно было вывести на консоль в двоичном формате - так будьте любезны формулировать вопросы корректно! Так вы и себе время сэкономите, и всем остальным участникам форума, т.к. не придется тратить время на разгадывание *ребусов*.

Answer (score 5):

Как вывести в консоль целочисленную переменную в бинарном представлении

```
#include <bitset>
........

int num = 99999;
cout << (bitset<sizeof(num)*8> (num)).to_string() << endl;
```

Печатается

```
00000000000000011000011010011111
```